# How to get the modified files(before and after) from git version server?

Tags: linux, git, diff

Now here is the commit id `41f9f4e392ab50db264e0328de7d69f1f10646eb`, I want to get this commit id code which were modified only.

I use `git show 41f9f4e392ab50db264e0328de7d69f1f10646eb` to see modified files, how can I download these both after modified and before modified version via Linux `git` command? In a word, I just want to compare the differences from before and after commit id `41f9f4e392ab50db264e0328de7d69f1f10646eb` to merge code easily.

Any idea will be helpful, thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to compare what's different, `git show` already shows the differences. Why do you need the files?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610208/how-to-retrieve-a-single-file-from-specific-revision-in-git

Comment: @ muru I need to get the midified files(before & after) then compare them, and merge them to another code branch, so I need the modified(before & after) files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all, I have found the correct way, here it is.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
from_id=$1
to_id=$2
#echo $from_id
#echo $to_id
diffpath='patch/diff.log'
newpath='patch/new/'
oldpath='patch/old/'
rm -rf patch
mkdir -p $newpath
mkdir -p $oldpath
git diff $from_id $to_id --raw > $diffpath
cat $diffpath | while  read line
do 
    #echo =====================================
    #echo $line
    OLD_IFS="$IFS"
    IFS=" "
    arr=($line)
    IFS="$OLD_IFS"   
    #echo ${arr[4]}
    filepath=${arr[4]##* }
    #echo $filepath
    newid=${arr[2]%%...}
    #echo $newid
    oldid=${arr[3]%%...}
    #echo $oldid  

   if [ "$newid"x != "0000000"x  ]; then   
     newfilepath=${newpath}${filepath}
     echo $newfilepath
     dirpath=${newfilepath%/*}
     echo $dirpath
     mkdir -p ${dirpath}
     git cat-file -p $newid >  ${newfilepath}
   fi

   if [ "$oldid"x != "0000000"x  ]; then 
     oldfilepath=${oldpath}${filepath} 
     echo $oldfilepath
     dirpath=${oldfilepath%/*}
     echo $dirpath   
     mkdir -p ${dirpath}
     git cat-file -p $oldid >  ${oldfilepath}
   fi   
done
```

You will found the new directory named patch in current working directory after doing this.

Answer (score 2):

To see the state of files before and after a given commit, check out its parent:

```
git checkout 41f9f4e3~1
```

then the commit itself:

```
git checkout 41f9f4e3
```

*However*, it’s hardly ever necessary to look at details of a change in this way. In your case, to apply a commit to another branch, cherry pick it:

```
git checkout ${target_branch}
git cherry-pick -x 41f9f4e3
```

(replacing `${target_branch}` as appropriate). The `-x` option adds a comment in the commit message with the origin of the cherry-pick.